# How to revise element's attribute values with substring in XML with XLS in multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, code-snippets

I am trying to change category "name" values in all nodes in this XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<offer xmlns:iof="********" xmlns:iaiext="******" file_format="IOF" generated="***" expires="***" version="3.0" extensions="yes">
  <products currency="EUR" iof_translation_generated="no" language="eng">
    <product id="170" currency="EUR" code_on_card="******" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" type="regular" vat="23.0" site="1">
      <producer id="1404978613" name="Test"/>
      <category id="1214554589" name="Cell phone screwdrivers"/>
      <category_idosell id="2898" path="Hardware &gt; Tools"/>
      <unit id="0" name="pc."/>
      <warranty id="2" type="seller" period="12" name="Cell phone accessories"/>
      <price gross="1.1" net="0.9"/>
    </product>
    <product id="411" currency="EUR" code_on_card="******" producer_code_standard="OTHER" type="regular" vat="23.0" site="1">
      <producer id="1404978613" name="Test"/>
      <category id="1214554594" name="Service Tools"/>
      <category_idosell id="2898" path="Hardware &gt; Tools"/>
      <unit id="0" name="pc."/>
      <warranty id="1" type="seller" period="6" name="Cell phone spare parts"/>
      <price gross="10.84" net="8.82"/>
    </product>
</products>
</offer>
```

with this XSL snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
  
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="category/@name">
   
        <xsl:element name="category">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//category_idosell[1]/@path, ' &gt; ')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'///'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//category_idosell[1]/@path, ' &gt; ')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'///'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="//category[1]/@name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works when I use it in a single node but when I have more nodes (products) it give me this error:

```
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring-before() ("Hardware > Tools", "Hardware > Tools")
```

can someone help me with what do I miss and how to make it work?
thank you in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your template matches the `name` **atribute** and replaces it with a `category` **element** having its own  `name` atribute. I doubt that's what you really want - even though you say that "it works".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a bit ambiguous, because both products have the same value in `category_idosell/@path`. AFAICT, you want to do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="category/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../../category_idosell/@path, ' &gt; ')"/>
        <xsl:text>///</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(../../category_idosell/@path, ' &gt; ')"/>
        <xsl:text>///</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

or even more simply:

```
<xsl:template match="category/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(../../category_idosell/@path, ' &gt; ', '///')"/>
        <xsl:text>///</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a template like e.g. `xsl:template match="category/@name"` the context node changes and in your case is that `name` attribute node so you want to write path expressions relative to that node like `../../category_idosell[1]/@path` and not absolute paths starting with `//` searching the whole document. Based on that and the excellent comment that your code tries to create an element while you just seem to want to change an attribute node's value I think you want something along the lines of

```
  <xsl:template match="category/@name">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"
        select="concat(substring-before(../../category_idosell[1]/@path, ' &gt; '), '///',substring-after(../../category_idosell[1]/@path, ' &gt; '),'///', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what output you want, so it's hard to correct your code.

If you want to take the value from the first product in the document, use

```
(//category_idosell)[1]
```

If you want to take the value from the current product, use

```
../category_idosell
```

Comment: the output I want is in each product the category to be like this:
<category name="Hardware///Tools///Cell phone screwdrivers"/></category>
<category name="Hardware///Tools///Service Tools"/></category>
but with all XML structure just revise the category